# Attempting to run a game (DFO) on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, launcher, games

As the title says, there's a game I'm very much dying to play since it's re-release, that game being DFO (http://www.dfoneople.com/). However, it seems to not be playing terribly nice with Wine.

I've tried every other solution that I'm able to, considering the fact that I'm a bit technologically illiterate. My internal HDD fried as well as the connecting cables, forcing me to use an external harddrive as my computer, hence why my constant attempts with installing Windows have failed, considering the fact that they locked it down pretty hard to any of that sort of shenanigan and I simply don't have the money to shell out for a brand new computer. On Ubuntu, I've been able to run things such as League at a near-flawless level, so transfer speed between computer and HDD isn't something I foresee being an issue.

As for the actual issue: Wine actually sets it up pretty fine in terms of the launcher, the latter beginning it's download more often than not to completion. Then I log in through the launcher, but the "Play" button doesn't ungray itself and demands I log in. Any attempt to interact with the launcher beyond this causes it to cease responding.

Is there any way to make this thing work or is it just that ingrained in Windows?

Comment: You can easily determine the level of wine support for a specific application by checking the wine app db here: https://appdb.winehq.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround reported [here:](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22152)

Pando Media Booster (PMB) based installers don't work (Atlantica Online, League of Legends, LotRO)

(prepending GC_DONT_GC=1 to the command line works around)

Much as it pains me to say so, If all else fails you could just run Windows under VirtualBox. I've resorted to such tactics to accomplish things that just weren't possible otherwise.

Comment: Wasn't PMB generally removed from most all games after they were bought out and turned malicious? Either way, I've tried the workaround and the installer began to do it's thing, but now I'm unable to log in at all. Every attempt spits out this in the terminal:



fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 28



Needless to say, I'm incredibly thankful for your help and any further of such if you know what I can do.

Comment: I don't know the history of PMB so I can't comment on that. Updated Answer